# How to find avaiable time slots in an Appointments table using Django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have a Django model that models patients making Appointments with doctors, like so:

```
class Appointment(Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    finish = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

I want to find available time slots that have at least a certain length between a range of datetimes, like this:

```
def find_timeslots(timeslot_length, start_datetime, finish_datetime): 
    ....
```

Some observations:

- The difference from start to finish is at most 8 hours
- Appointments can go over the day (e.g., I can have an appointment that starts at 2016-03-21 22:00:00 and ends at 2016-03-22 06:00:00).

My current solution is getting all Appointments from a doctor and iterate from **start_datetime** until **finish_datetime** in **timeslot_length** intervals, checking for conflicts. If it has no conflict, I store a (start, finish) tuple in a list.

It somewhat works, but it doesn't seems like an elegant solution. What's a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a unique slot ID for every appointment slot. You can make  combination of date + time + doctorid as the slot ID (depends upon you). When you save an appointment save it with the slot id you generated and when you want to check for conflicts you need not iterate from start time to end time, just check whether the slot id you are about to save exists or not.

Comment: The problem that I see with this approach is that there will (probably) be a lot of unused slots, specially if the number of doctors rise quickly. Seems like too much trouble when my current model works fine for most cases, except when trying to suggest an available slot.

Comment: You don't need to save every slot in the database. Just generate the slots programmatically and only save the ones that are booked. For this you need to maintain a pattern in the slot id